# yeoman is not working in windows

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

Node version 0.10.4 and npm 1.2.18  is installed in windows 64 bit.after that I use 
'npm install -g yo' to install yeoman .But yo is not installed in my machine.After installation when I write 'yo --version',then error gives that yo is not recognized as an internal or external command.Please suggest how to install yeoman in windows.

Comment: Just update the node and npm with the latest-version v0.10.28 and after that install yo.Its works.

Answer (score 24):

Node seems to be installed in "c:\Program Files\nodejs\" however yo seems to get installed in "c:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\"

If you check this folder there should be a yo.cmd file. If there isn't then you have another issue and this will not fix our problem.

You can use the %APPDATA% variable as well.

You'll have to add this new path to your %PATH% environment variable.

Fix:

1. Right click "My Computer"
2. Click on Properties
3. Click Advanced system settings
4. click on Advanced tab.
5. click the Environment Variables... button
6. find the PATH variable and add to its value %APPDATA%\npm\ (use semicolon ";" to separate what you add from what is already there)
7. make sure that there are no extra spaces around the semicolon

Comment: On this f**king windows everything is different.... Your solution saved my day...